# Visibility of approval requests for delegated approvers

Tags: approval-process

Would like to know if its possible for a delegated approver to see open approval requests in their home queue? Currently only the identified approver can see these under "Items to approve" on the home page however we have some delegated approvers that would like visibility of these requests too. Now all they have to go on is the email request that they received or to pull a report that shows open approvals for the actual approver they are delegating for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is resolution yet to visibility for the delegated approver. But as you said there is a workaround

Below is the Knowledge article link

[Delegated Approver cannot see anything in the 'Items to Approve' list](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000330521&type=1&mode=1)